# Trying to run a python variable as command line arg

Tags: python, scripting, command-line-interface

I'm trying to pass a variable that I set to a list of options for a command line argument, but can't figure out how to use that variable to be recognized in command prompt.

```
import argparse, sys, os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="robocopy script"
    )
    
    # Add the parameters positional/optional
    parser.add_argument('robocopy', help="robocopy")

    # Parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    src = input("source directory: ")
    des = input("destination directory: ")
    opt = "/E /Z /ZB /R:5 /TBD /NP /V /MT:16"
    print(args)
    result = None
    if args.robocopy == "robocopy":
        result = print("robocopy " + src + ":/ " + des + ":/ " + opt)

    print(result)
os.system('cmd /k "result"')
```

Comment: Don't use `os.system`; use `subprocess.call`.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @user1803784 for the expected output.

```
import argparse, sys, os, subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="robocopy script"
    )
    
    # Add the parameters positional/optional
    parser.add_argument('robocopy', help="robocopy")

    # Parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    src = input("source directory: ")
    des = input("destination directory: ")
    opt = "/E /Z /ZB /R:5 /TBD /NP /V /MT:16"
    print(args)
    result = None
    if args.robocopy == "robocopy":
# Changes made to original code
        result = "robocopy " + src + ":/ " + des + ":/ " + opt

# Changes made to original code
cmd = 'cmd /k %s' % result
os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
result = print("robocopy " + src + ":/ " + des + ":/ " + opt)
```

calls the print function which does not return a string. Remove the print function and try that.

```
result = "robocopy " + src + ":/ " + des + ":/ " + opt
```

I haven't tested the code completely but that is the first thing that
jumped out when I looked at the code.

Ok the second part that concerned me was the line:

```
os.system('cmd /k "result"')
```

I did a test in this same format to see if the varibale value would be substituted in the string. But it didn't work. Hence I did the below:

```
cmd = 'cmd /k %s' % result
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: yes that worked exactly like I wanted it. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: No problem os.system is indeed an old function as @chepner indicated and his suggestion of using subprocess.call is the recommend function to use when calling a command. Nonetheless its your choice.

Comment: I'll just stick with this for now